# How to use MediaPlayer which plays music stored in a folder found in the asset

Tags: java, android, path, android-mediaplayer

I am creating an android app from android studio.

My intention is to have a function to play different songs depending on the string argument.

```
 MediaPlayer mysound;
public void play(String song){
mysound = Mediaplayer.create(this, "../../../../asset/soundlib/" + song);
mysound.play();
}
```

I tried the R.assets.song. It just does not work.

Is there a way to have the song named C.mp3? It says that they should not be capitalized and all of the arguments taken are basically chords like C A F...

Thank you

[image: w]

Comment: If the media player can play from an input stream then yes it can be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For android java use

```
void test_mp(String file_name)
{
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = null;


            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            try {
                AssetFileDescriptor afd = act.getAssets().openFd(file_name);
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                afd.close();
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
```

So for your case, you can call it like `test_mp("SoundLib/A.mp3");`

Answer (score 0):

Try below code for play assets song :

```
 fun playSound(context: Context, assetsFileName: String?) {
        try {
            val mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()
            val descriptor: AssetFileDescriptor = context.getAssets().openFd(assetsFileName!!)
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(
                descriptor.getFileDescriptor(),
                descriptor.getStartOffset(),
                descriptor.getLength()
            )
            descriptor.close()
            mediaPlayer.prepare()
            mediaPlayer.isLooping = false
            mediaPlayer.start()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```

Thanks